# How servlet filter will dispatch error message on request page?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have written a servlet filter which is configured to be invoked for each url (/*). On the basis of some condition, if the condition is passed, I want to proceed normal execution by `chain.doFilter(request,response`), I also want to open same request URL with error message..

"say value entered in particular textbox is incorrect". Is this possible?

Do I have to use `response.sendRedirect(request.getURL())`? I hope I wont end up in infinite loop as I have configured filter on each URL. I am doing validation check on request parameter.

Comment: I wouldn't do validation in a `Filter`, especially one mapped to `/*` I'd try and be a bit more targetted.

Comment: ok..there are some validation which needs to be done for each request..so that why i am trying with filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do the same as you'd do in a servlet: perform a forward.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

A filter is by default not (re)invoked on a forward. Additional advantage is that the JSP reuses the same request and thus you can just set the validation error messages as a request attribute without the need for session or cookie based workarounds/hacks.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this isn't entirely the right approach. Form-specific validation job should be performed in a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), not in a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). If you'd like to keep your servlet(s) DRY, then look at the front controller pattern or just adopt a MVC framework which already offers a front controller servlet and decent validation out the box, such as [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) or [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-mvc/info).

Comment: Thank you..just one more help ,..can u tell me is there any way to know that request on this filter came from which jsp? note my httpRequest.getUri() gives an action string and not jsp..which is mapped to the controller of spring

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should do it in a front controller. Usually a front controller knows precisely which JSP it is. But as you're apparently using Spring's front controller, why don't you just use its validation facilities?

Comment: since it is a generic check for all request so thought of doing it in request filter..can you kindly let me know if I write a spring interceptor then will the task be easier..since i want  a check for all request

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I can't go in detail. In JSF it's just a matter of adding `required="true"` attribute to the input component, or nesting a `<f:validator>` tag in the input component.